# Undo selecting to use partition as swap and recover data

Tags: data-recovery

I don't know how to explain this as I don't know what has happened.
So I was trying to install Ubuntu from a Flash drive and didn't knew what to do. Somewhere during the Initial steps of Setup I Checked that "something else.."

[image]

Where it showed this..(this is not my PC) just like that sda5 one of my drive was sda3 and was about 336 GB in size which I used as "swap" (IDK what is that either).

I used sda5 as the "root file system" thingy. Now my problem is, when the installation was over and it rebooted it directly Started Windows and I saw My 336 Gb drive missing in Windows as well as Ubuntu. TBH I don't know what I have done, where this is heading..I am beyond Terrified :C . HELP!

And this is what it shows in My Windows 7 now:

[image]

Comment: Did you do the install inside VirtualBox, and did you do any changes outside of VirtualBox?

Comment: No I didn't used anything named "VirtualBox".

Comment: Oh ok did you use someone else's screenshot? (A actual one would help alot). BTW Windows by default can't read Ubuntu's default filesystems (ext4 and swap), unless it has [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) or something

Comment: @Wilf I think it's pretty clear. He ran the installer, told it to use the existing 336GB Data (or whatever) partition from Windows as swap and now realizes that this was not what he would have intended and hopes there is a way to recover the data that once resided inside what now is used as Ubuntu's swap.

Comment: @ChandanPineappleAcharya That's why especially beginners should not play with advanced features, at least not without making a system backup before doing so!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened @ByteCommander . Is there any hope to recover it ?

Comment: I tried using a software called Testdisk 7.0  in Windows(as I don't know how to make it work in Ubuntu) and ended up with this.. after an hour http://i21.servimg.com/u/f21/19/31/28/30/110.png